# wcf service host in windows service-the program couldnt find the end point

Tags: .net, wcf, service, communication, 3-tier

I new in three tiers projects and wcf so I made a three tiers sample project-

when i install the wcf service (I used windows service-network service) and open my windows form exe which using the wcf service in the same computer it worked fine but when I tried to open the windows form exe in another computer I got an error message:
"Could not find endpoint element with name "xxx" and contract 'xx.xx' in the servicemodel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application"

I opened the port that I need in order that it will work and I tried to check with ping command that there is no problem with the connection of the computers

what should I do that it will work?

here is my config files:

the app.config of my wcf-service library:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceBehavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="WcfSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="WcfSvcBasicMexHttpEndPoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="WcfSvcTcpEndPoint"
      contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxx:8080/service" />
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://xxx:8181/service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

the app.config in my host-windows service-it the same as the config of the wcf service.

the app.config of the user interface (a windows form):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WcfSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="WcfSvcTcpEndPoint" />
  </netTcpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WcfSvcBasicMexHttpEndPoint">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://xxx:8080/service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WcfSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent"
    name="WcfSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" />
  <endpoint address="http://xxx:8080/service/mex" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WcfSvcBasicMexHttpEndPoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent"
    name="WcfSvcBasicMexHttpEndPoint" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://xxx:8181/service" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WcfSvcTcpEndPoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IStudent"
    name="WcfSvcTcpEndPoint">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="User-PC\User" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I am using in the connection named "WcfSvcTcpEndPoint" in my windows form project.

```
       protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
        {
            myServiceHost.Close();
        }
        myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
        myServiceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
        {
            myServiceHost.Close();
            myServiceHost = null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ping occurs over a different port than you are using most likely, if you turn the firewall off both machines does it work? What is your config file, you may not have the services configured correctly.

Comment: I turned the firewall off in the computers and it still didn't work, I added to my question the config files (I follow a tutorial when I made it)

Comment: Might sound simple, but did you check this? _This might be because no configuration file was found for your application_

Comment: I didn't notice that-I forgot to copy the configuration file together with the exe-thanks:)